# Unserialize an array of bytes taking account of its useful length

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I have an array of bytes whose length equals XXX. It contains a serialized object which I want to unserialise (ie. : I want to create a copy of this object from these stored bytes).

But I have a constraint : the useful length of my bytes array. Indeed, I want to take in consideration the latter to unserialise (ie. : **the serialized object can be shorter than the array's size**).

I hope you will understand easier with my two little methods (the first serialises, while the last unserialises) :

```
byte[] toBytes() throws IOException {
    byte[] array_bytes;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byte_array_output_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutput object_output = new ObjectOutputStream(byte_array_output_stream);
    object_output.writeObject(this);
    object_output.close();
    array_bytes = byte_array_output_stream.toByteArray();

    return array_bytes;
}
```

And the current unserialisation method (which is "wrong" for the moment because I don't use the useful length) :

```
static Message fromBytes(byte[] bytes, int length) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, ClassCastException {
    Message message;

    ByteArrayInputStream byte_array_input_stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInput object_input = new ObjectInputStream(byte_array_input_stream);
    message = (Message) object_input.readObject();
    object_input.close();

    return message;
}
```

As you can see, `readObject` doesn't need a length, and I must : that's a problem, and perhaps I should NOT use this method.

Thus, my question is : **With or without using `readObject`, how could I take in consideration the useful length (ie. : "payload" ?) of my bytes array ?**

Comment: Use [DataOutputStream.write(buf, offset, len)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int)). Write the used length (int, short or byte) before. For reading there are suitable read methods as well in DataInputStream. Writing always must match the read method. Therefore if you don't use readObject you can't use writeObject as well.

Comment: I must get an Object, and this function is `void` : that's a problem no ?

Comment: No method from `DataInputStream` returns an object :/

Comment: Lol you don't wand an object you want a `byte[]`. Create it in the size you need and use with `DataInputStream.readFully(buf)`.

Comment: I really want an object, from my array of bytes (when unserializing)

Comment: Create a new `Message` instance and set it's message body using the read `byte[]`. Java object serialization should usually be avoided as it has security issues, drawbacks and the serialized objects are pretty large.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `Message` class implements `Serializable`.
In this case, when you `write` your message, it gets automatically serialized from the java runtime, as explained in the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

I cannot be sure how or why you might find part of the generated byte array as *not useful*, since it is all part of the serialized instance.

However, I might suggest that you follow the [Externalizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) interface way:
your `Message` class will implement `Externalizable`. Then you have the option of controlling how exactly your class gets serialized and de-serialized in `writeExternal(ObjectOutput out)` and `readExternal(ObjectInput in)` methods respectively, where you can write the length you want in the stream, read it back, and/or keep only the required amount of bytes.

Comment: Thank you, but I must not use any other interfaces than `Serializable` for `Message` :/ Perhaps I could create my `Message` object attribute per attribute...